# How do you use MySQL's source command to import large files in windows

Tags: mysql, import, xampp

I have a large (~150mb) sql file that I am trying to import.  It is too large to do it through PHPMyAdmin even splitting it into many pieces and it is too large to import through a php script as it times out after 30 seconds of processing the script. So I'm looking for how to directly import the file from MySQL command line.

Searching online shows that I want to either use `database_name < file_name.sql` or `source file_name.sql` but I can't get either of these to work.

Using `<` gives the generic MySQL syntax error while using `source` give a slightly more promising `failed to open file 'file_name.sql', error: 2` so I am inclined to think that the source command is on the right track.

I am in windows and am using xampp as a localhost server (note I'm only trying to import this file on the localhost so that I can execute the sql).  I've tried placing the file in  `xampp\mysql\bin` and `xampp\mysql\data\database_name`.

Any suggestions of how to import this .sql file into MySQL either from the MySQL command line or by any other means would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're attempting to use `database_name` literally or not. The command should be `mysql -u youruser -h yourhost -p database_name < file_name.sql` where an example would be: `mysql -u henry -h localhost -p mydb < file_name.sql`

Comment: I'm not using `database_name` literally. It's just a place holder for the actual name of the database I'm wanting to import to.  I've been trying to use the commands from the mysql console rather than cmd because I get errors relating to `mysql` not being a recognized command or `<` being reserved for future use when I try to execute from cmd.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

With xampp I think you need to use the full path at the command line, something like this, perhaps:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u {username} -p {databasename} < file_name.sql
```

Comment: I get the same error mentioned by Daniel Nill: < is reserved for future versions. How can I get around that?

Comment: ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: ''. Can you tell me a solution to this?

Comment: Alternatively you can add C:\xampp\mysql\bin to your PATH and use mysql anywhere

Comment: If you encounter the error '< is reserved for future use' it is because of powershell. Try to run this command from the cmd (or launch a cmd interpreter from within the powershell by typing cmd). Worked in my case (win 10)

Answer (score 83):

On Windows this should work (note the forward slash and that the whole path is not quoted and that spaces are allowed)

`USE yourdb;`

`SOURCE D:/My Folder with spaces/Folder/filetoimport.sql;`

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for how spaces were handled and your solution came up despite it being slightly off topic.  Both forward `/` and backward `\\` slashes worked just fine for me as well.  No single quotes, no double quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

Don't use `"source"`, it's designed to run a small number of `sql queries` and display the output, not to import large databases.

I use `Wamp Developer` (not `XAMPP`) but it should be the same.

What you want to do is use the `MySQL Client` to do the work for you.

1. Make sure `MySQL` is running.
2. Create your database via `phpMyAdmin` or the `MySQL shell`.
3. Then, run `cmd.exe`, and change to the directory your `sql` file is
   located in.
4. Execute: `mysql -u root -p database_name_here < dump_file_name_here.sql`
5. Substitute in your `database name` and `dump file name`.
6. Enter your `MySQL root account password` when prompted (if no password set, remove the "-p" switch).

This assumes that `mysql.exe` can be located via the environmental path, and that `sql` file is located in the directory you are running this from. Otherwise, use full paths.

Comment: thanks, this worked once i read your note: "Enter your MySQL root account password when prompted."

Comment: Ah!, it does not required a semi colon at the last. Now, it is back to same error in import. Is there any error suppressing method!

Comment: I remember that I was using command line more than these phpmyadmin etc. Wasted so many hrs. Just used mysqldump to export and then mysql ... to import and it worked like a charm. phpMyAdmin was not exporting correctly.

Comment: you are correct. I tried to insert 1.3M records using source command. It took more than 2 hours.

Comment: The source is actually preferred. So if you have sone insert statement per table you can follow the progress of the import.

Answer (score 16):

**Option 1.** you can do this using single cmd where D is my xampp or wampp install folder so i use this where mysql.exe install and second option database name and last is sql file so replace it as your then run this

You can try this:

```
mysql -u root -p test < /test.sql
```

Another option

```
D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p databse_name < D:\yoursqlfile.sql
```

**Option 1 for wampp**

```
D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p databse_name< D:\yoursqlfile.sql
```

change your folder and mysql version

**Option 2** Suppose your current path is which is showing command prompt

```
C:\Users\shafiq;
```

then change directory using `cd..`
then goto your mysql directory where your xampp installed. Then `cd..` for change directory. then go to bin folder.

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin;
```

`C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u {username} -p {database password}`.then please enter when you see enter password in command prompt.

choose database using

```
mysql->use test (where database name test)
```

then put in source sql in bin folder.

then last command will be

```
mysql-> source test.sql (where test.sql is file name which need to import)
```

then press enter

**This is full command**

```
C:\Users\shafiq;
C:\xampp\mysql\bin
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u {username} -p {database password}
 mysql-> use test
 mysql->source test.sql
```

Comment: This saved my day. I had the problem that the mysql server had gone away while I tried to import the file the "normal way" by using: mysql -u username -p database < file.sql. So thanks for providing an alternative way.

Comment: "this app can't run on your pc" 

Answer (score 5):

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p testdatabase < C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\databasebackup.sql
```

That worked for me to import 400MB file into my database.

Comment: Also works on WampServer to load a schema: `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin>mysql -u root -p < C:\Users\rico\Desktop\sakila-db\sakila-schema.sql`

Answer (score 3):

For importing a large SQL file using the command line in MySQL.

First go to file path at the command line.
Then,

Option 1:

```
mysql -u {user_name} -p{password} {database_name}  < your_file.sql
```

It's give a warning mesaage : Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Done.Your file will be imported.

Option 2:

```
mysql -u {user_name} -p {database_name}  < your_file.sql
```

in this you are not provide sql password then they asked for password just enter password and your file will be imported.

Answer (score 2):

use mysql `source` command to avoid redirection failures, especially on windows.

```
mysql [-u <username>] [-p<password>] <databasename> -e "source /path/to/dump.sql"
```

where e for "Execute command"

On Windows, please remember to use double quote for sql command.

However, either backslash \ or slash / will work on Windows.

Comment: I found that using \ in path under Windows very specifically did *not* work.  I had to substitute  \ to / to make it work, e.g. as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/21796949/489865 solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I had the same problem but I tried many different states and I came to it:
SOURCE doesn't work with ; at the end in my case:

```
SOURCE D:\Barname-Narmafzar\computer programming's languages\SQL\MySQL\dataAug-12-2019\dataAug-12-2019.sql;
```

and the error was:

`ERROR: Unknown command '\B'.
    '>`

it also didn't work with a quotation for the address.
But it works without ; at the end:

```
SOURCE D:\Barname-Narmafzar\computer programming's languages\SQL\MySQL\dataAug-12-2019\dataAug-12-2019.sql
```

But remember to use USE database_name; before that.
I think it's so because the SOURCE or USE or HELP are for the Mysql itself and they are not such query codes although when you write HELP it says:

"Note that all text commands must be first on line and end with ; ".

but here doesn't work.

I should say that I have done it in CMD and I didn't try it in Mysql Workbench.
That was it

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE1ZV.png)

Answer (score 1):

On my Xampp set-up I was able to use the following to import a database into MySQL:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u {username goes here} -p {leave password blank} {database name} < /path/to/file.sql [enter]
```

My personal experience on my local machine was as follows:
**Username:** Root
**Database Name:** testdatabase
**SQL File Location:** databasebackup.sql is located on my desktop

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p testdatabase < C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\databasebackup.sql
```

That worked for me to import my 1GB+ file into my database.

Answer (score 1):

**Username as root without password**

```
mysql -h localhost -u root databasename < dump.sql
```

I have faced the problem on my local host as i don't have any password for root user. You can use it without -p password as above. If it ask for password, just hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

On windows:
Use explorer to navigate to the folder with the .sql file.
Type cmd in the top address bar. Cmd will open.
Type:

```
"C:\path\to\mysql.exe" -u "your_username" -p "your password" < "name_of_your_sql_file.sql"
```

Wait a bit and the sql file will have been executed on your database.
Confirmed to work with MariaDB in feb 2018.