# how should i import a huge table in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, upload, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 300,000 rows. then when i import it, it will uploaded almost 200,000 rows then phpmyadmin kills the upload with this error:

> **Fatal error:** Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\import\sql.php on line 246

**Note:** 'on line 246' is not unchanged. sometimes is 130 or 182.

It should be noted that i changed *(increased)* all the parameter in php.ini file.
something such as:

```
post_max_size       = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time  = 5000
max_input_time      = 5000
memory_limit        = 1000M
```

Still i could not upload my huge table .....! In fact, my problem is time limit.  What suggestions do you have ?

Comment: Log into mysql shell and `source` the sql file.

Comment: Why not split it up into chunks?

Comment: you should also look into apache configuration for timeouts

Comment: @Vohuman i logged the sql file and don't find any appropriate variable for change.

Comment: @tadman really should i do that ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "don't find any appropriate variable for change"?

Comment: @Vohuman What exactly do you mean by "Log into mysql shell and source the sql file" ?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163694/how-do-you-use-mysqls-source-command-to-import-large-files-in-windows

Comment: @Sajad Normally I roll in things like this through the `mysql` command-line tool since it is much more reliable than `phpmyadmin`. If you can do that, give it a shot.

Comment: @Vohuman aha, but i'm in local (my PC), i have not a server with linux OS , then how should i use command line ?

Comment: You don't have to have a Linux OS installed. It seems you are using a XAMPP stack, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698914/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-with-xampp-for-windows

Comment: @Vohuman you right...! tnx alot. just are you from iran ? can you speak persian ?

Comment: @Sajad Yes, I am. Bale, mitunam.

Comment: @Vohuman wow !! vaghaan khoshHalam ke ye irani ro inja mibinam ! 87,014 reputation ??? damet garm baba !! movafagh bashi

Comment: @Vohuman I did it, tnx Bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve my problem with the help of *@vohuman*.

To get rid of the limitations of import *(and even export)*, you should use command line, Or in the words of @vohuman:

> **@vohuman:** 'Log into mysql shell and `source` the sql file'

So, to import a `.sql` file (for windows and xampp), you should do these:

**step1:** put your .sql file on C drive, then your file address will be: `c:\filename.sql`

**step2:**  open CMD and type this:

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin
```

**step3:** then type this line into command line to import your file:

```
mysql -u {username} -p {databasename} < c:\filename.sql
```

> - By default `{username}` is `root`.
> - If you use the password, you should use `-p{passwordname}` in above line. *(between `-p` and `passwordname` isn't any space.)*
> - Also you can use any other address. `c:\filename.sql` is for example.

**step4:** finally, check your database and uploaded file. *(for example use phpmyadmin)*

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is ok, but you have to notice that if you are running phpmyadmin with an alias conf file, inside the alias you can set the php variables right to the alias, and will not be affected with the directives that you set in the global php.ini, check the alias (if is the case)

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "/path/phpmyadmin4.4.6/"
<Directory "/path/phpmyadmin4.4.6/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```