# Importing sample database into phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, uwamp

I am trying to import a sample database "employees.sql" from official phpMyAdmin webpage. I am using uwamp server and getting the following error when using phpMyAdmin "import" option:

```
Unrecognized statement type. (near "source" at position 0)
```

.SQL FILE AT LINE WHERE ERROR IS REPORTED:

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
```

I am not sure what to change to successfully import the database. I also tried different things like putting load_departments.dump in quotes, but it still didn't work.
[image: Screenshot of error.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do you use MySQL's source command to import large files in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163694/how-do-you-use-mysqls-source-command-to-import-large-files-in-windows)

must read and you will definitely get many ideas! 
I think you should fire source command from cmd (command prompt)

Comment: Tried it, but now even that line is getting reported as an error.

Comment: are you using windows?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create an empty database and import that sql file inside of it. Check it out..

Comment: I actually tried this. I created a new database and under import I tried to import the .sql file.

Comment: I hope you will get from here  ->  https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.5.5/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... Apparently phpMyAdmin got installed along with my uwamp server and I got the sample database from this page yes, the official phpmyadmin page.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: MySQL Server was installed and you have downloaded the employees database from [github](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db/archive/master.zip). Unzip the package and go to the directory from command prompt.

1. Enter the following command and on prompt, provide the sql password.

```html
mysql -u root -p -t < employees.sql
```

2. Verify your installation by entering the following command.

```html
 mysql -u root -p -t < test_employees_md5.sql
```