How to revert MySQL DB after testing in a docker-compose setup?
I am using Playwright Python for end-to-end testing of my docker-compose project.
The compose file looks like this:
services:
  project-database:
    ...
    hostname: database-host
    networks:
      - project-network
  
  project-frontend:
    ...
    hostname: frontend-host
    networks:
      - project-network

  project-backend:
    ...
    hostname: backend-host
    networks:
      - project-network
  
  project-tests:
    ...
    container_name: project-tests
    networks:
      - project-network

To execute my tests I do:
> docker compose build
> docker compose up -d
> docker compose run --rm project-tests pytest /playwright/tests

With the mysql-connector I can connect to the DB with connection = mysql.connector.connect(user= 'admin', host= 'database-host', (..) and then assert stuff from my webpage with the content of my database.
Example for one of the tests in /playwright/tests:
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect

def simple_test(page: Page) -> None:
  page.goto(http://frontend-host/articles)
  page.locator("#new-article-name").fill("Sample")
  page.locator("#create-new-article-button").click()

  connection.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM article")
  article = cursor.fetchone()

  expect( page.locator("#article-list") ).to_contain_text( article[1])

So far so good, but for testing purposes, I want to control the database, for example resetting after tests as not to cross-contaminate the test results or loading different scenarios before testing.
My SQL files are located in the database Docker container under /schemas/.
I tried using the mysql-connector like connection.cursor.execute("SOURCE /schemas/test_setting_1.sql") in an after_script which results in a syntax error (got the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21796949/20208551 )
I also tried subprocess.run( cmd.split() ) with cmd = "mysql -h database-host -u user -ppassword database < /schemas/test_setting_1.sql" and while it tells me not to use my password on the commandline, it doesn't do anything else.
connection.start_transaction() with connection.rollback() also doesn't do anything, (and shouldn't in this case if I understand it correctly but I am trying anything at this point)
Is there a simple solution (like loading a backup, make a snapshot and revert to it, ...) in PYTHON, preferably using the connector?
To be clear, I need to be able to set the state of the database dynamically to a predefined state during the Playwright test run. Reverting to an empty DB is just one case, so TRUNCATE is not the solution, at least I don't see how.
